# Characters to hex

Tags: shell, hex, ascii, terminfo

I need some help in Shell scripting.
I have a folder with single-letter folder names starting with 1 and ending with the small letter z: `[1-9A-Za-z]`.
Now, I want to rename the folders to its hexadecimal value:
`1` to `31` ... `z` to `7A`.

I wanted to fix this with a for loop, but now I'm stuck here.
I had never programmed with Shell, but with C and ASM.

[Edit]: Open your Terminfo folder. On OS X (10.9.1): `/usr/share/terminfo`.
There you can see hex values.
Now, on my iPhone, they are in single ASCII characters. Therefore the terminal can't find any file.

Comment: No. I dont know how to start.

Comment: I can set the index to 49. This is 31h and represents ASCII 1. But after this?

Comment: Do you have the program `hd` available?  If you echo a string (filename) to it, it will output some junk wrapped around the hex representation of the characters in the string.  That's one possibility; I'm far from certain that it is the best.  Do you have Perl or Python on hand? Could you use one of them?  It would be relatively straight-forward using Perl and not much harder using Python (possibly easier if you're more fluent in Python than Perl).

Comment: The script must work on a jailbreaked iOS. Perl and Python would work.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that given a filename `1animosityz`, you want to rename the file to `31616e696d6f736974797a`?  Is the 'starting with 1 and ending in z' best handled by shell metacharacters: `1*z`?  Or do you mean you want any name to be mapped to its hex representation?

Comment: No. The folder itself has only one character.

Comment: Ah; so folder `1` goes to `31`; folder `z` goes to `7A` (upper-case required?); and any other single character maps to its double-character hex equivalent? `for d in ?; do mv "$d" $(printf "%2X" "'$d'"); done`?  And do you mean `/usr/share/terminfo`?  A single-letter name is the classic naming convention on other variants of Unix, but on Mac OS X 10.9.1, the names are 2 hex digits (lower case letters used on my machine).

Comment: Then Apple had changed it from letters to hex digits with iOS 7.

Comment: Actually, Apple used a documented feature of ncurses, to work with OSX's case-insensitive filesystem (see [changelog](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20071117)).  Whether that is appropriate for iOS 7 has not been mentioned.  iOS 7 was released about 7 years after the ncurses feature was introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any appropriate directory, you can try:

```
$ mkdir terminfo
$ cd terminfo
$ mkdir {0..9} {a..z}
$ ls
0   3   6   9   c   f   i   l   o   r   u   x
1   4   7   a   d   g   j   m   p   s   v   y
2   5   8   b   e   h   k   n   q   t   w   z
$ for d in ?; do mv "$d" $(printf "%2X" "'$d'"); done
$ ls
30  33  36  39  63  66  69  6C  6F  72  75  78
31  34  37  61  64  67  6A  6D  70  73  76  79
32  35  38  62  65  68  6B  6E  71  74  77  7A
$
```

If you use `echo mv` instead of just `mv`, you can see the operations the shell does. You can use `%2x` in place of `%2X` to get names like `7a`, which matches what I see in `/usr/share/terminfo` on my machine (but the file system is case-preserving and case-insensitive, so the upper-case should work).  You might also consider using `ln -s` instead of `mv`; that way, you have both the old names and the new names available, so old code and new code should be happy.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I will use ln -s.

Answer (score 2):

To rename a directories with a single-character name to the ascii hex value of that name:

```
for dir in [1-9A-Za-z]
do
    mv "$dir" "$(printf  "${2:-%x}" "'$dir")"
done
```

The above is based on code for converting ascii to hex using bash.  Thus, this script converts the character given as its first argument to its ascii hexadecimal value:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf  "${2:-%x}\n" "'$1"
```

So, for example, if you put that script in an executable file called char2hex.sh:

```
$ bash char2hex.sh 1
31
$ bash char2hex.sh z
7a
```

**MORE:**  The information below is for the first version of this question which asked for decimal values:

This script converts the character given as its first argument to its ascii decimal value:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf  "${3:-%d}\n" "'$1"
```

So, for example, if you put that script in an executable file called char2hex.sh:

```
$ char2hex.sh z
122
```

Comment: Now, it has to count from 1-9 then A-Z finally a-z.
But I think, your solution is not good.

Comment: I think there's a kernel of a good idea here.  Be aware that on Linux, `/usr/bin/printf` behaves differently from the `bash` built-in `printf` command.  Try: `/usr/bin/printf "%2X" "'z'"; echo` and `printf "%2X" "'z'"; echo`.  Consistency is a wonderful thing, Emerson notwithstanding.  (Tested: Ubuntu 12.04 derivative.)  The `printf` command will use its format string repeatedly if there are more arguments than there are conversion specifications in the format string.